# Downloading swf flash video doesn't work

Tags: video-streaming, flash, flash-video

Does anyone know how to download the actual flash video from the following site:
http://www.cbc.ca/player/News/Business/ID/2258963934/

I searched the source code and it seems like the video is located in 
http://www.cbc.ca/video/swf/UberPlayer.swf?clipId=2258963934&autoPlay=true

However, when I manually put it into the browser the video doesn't seem to load..Does anyone know why or how to download it???

Thanks!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using [VSO Downloader](http://www.vso-software.fr/products/downloader/vso-downloader.php?s=l), it works great with many sites, I think it can handle CBC.